# Raspberry Pi-2 with mainline Linux kernel

Tags: pi-2, kernel, driver, firmware

With [several](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=6d1c244803f2c013fb9c31b0904c01f1830b73ab) [nice](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9638685e32af961943b679fcb72d4ddd458eb18f) [commits](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=192cb07f7928e8cb09a9851e6c0f7478baa3bc6d) landing into the mainline of Linux Kernel for version 4.5, is it already possible to compile and boot a mainline kernel (e.g. 4.5-rc6) on a Raspberry Pi 2? If yes, then what is the simplest way to do so? What kernel configuration options do I need to set for basic Pi 2 hardware support (SD card, ethernet, usb, text mode video output)? Do I need some extra binary blobs?

Comment: I do not think it is impossible, but I have not tried and I do not think it would be very easy unless you already understood the structure of the kernel sourse first.  Note that the [rpi kernel source](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-4.5.y) is already available in a 4.5.x version, so if you can cross-compile or do it directly on the pi (note this will probably take hours), you are set in that sense.  However, it's not a direct answer to your central question.

Comment: I'm already cross compiling the working kernels from the rpi kernel sources (rpi-4.5.y branch). Once you turn off all the useless stuff, it takes perhaps 5 minutes on my 8-core i7-4700MQ.

Comment: Yes, compiling on a modern normal box is very fast.  For the Pi 2 this is easy because most distros come with an ARMv7 cross-compiler; for the other versions you need to build or acquire an ARMv6 tool chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the Raspberry Pi 2 support is present in 4.5, you're also looking for a .config that will work.  The changes for multi_v7_defconfig weren't ready for 4.5, so they're currently in [linux-next](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/).  That defconfig is still missing a couple of things:

```
CONFIG_BCM2835_WDT=y (enables reboot/shutdown)
CONFIG_SND_BCM2835_SOC_I2S=y (support for external audio DACs, not the 3.5mm jack)
CONFIG_DMA_BCM2835=y (only used for i2s currently)
CONFIG_PWM_BCM2835=y
```

Even with all of this, graphics doesn't work without [this series](https://github.com/anholt/linux/tree/drm-vc4-dt).

Note that if you're doing your own kernels, you want serial console so you can debug.  Otherwise you'll be staring at a dead computer and wondering why things don't work.

Comment: So, in principle, when mainline Linux Kernel 4.5 is released, it should be possible to boot it on an Raspberry Pi 2 (without DRM support) given a correct `.config` file?

Comment: Yes, it definitely should be.  I'm running upstream 4.5 rcs for my daily development work.